# Post metadata deletes itself

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I'm using a custom post type for a portfolio. I have a few option in there, bring saved by `update_post_meta()`, it seems to work fine, but then out of the blue (within the hour), the data deletes its self. I have looked in the DB and all custom metadata values are empty.

I'm a little stumped really.

Here's the code that's saving one of the options.

```
function update_colour_palette(){
    global $post;
    $color = get_post_custom($post->ID);
 $palette = $color["palette"][0];
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "palette", $_POST["palette"], $palette);
}
```

Any help, tips & tricks would be useful.

Comment: @PaulAllenDavis: How do you trigger `update_colous_palette()`? Because the post saves revisions multiple times via Ajax while the editor is open, you should check for this and not update the post meta if this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using this for a while to solve exactly your issue, I think I got it from the codex somewhere. But it works.

```
// verify if this is an auto save routine. 
// If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;
```

Comment: Seems to have fixed the issue for me. (Sorry for the 8 months delay, just had the same problem again)

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is in a post edit/ post save action, in which case you should add checks for user level and a nonce in there. If you don't then this can be called in all sorts of places where the post values don't exist.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I'll add that soon.