# Possible to turn off autosave for single custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

So I'm having an issue with my custom fields in my custom post type. For whatever reason the fields save and then clear somewhat randomly... I'm sure it's not random but I'm not sure what's triggering this to happen. Here's the code for my custom post type:

```
    // Custom Post Type: Strategic Giving
add_action('init', 'giving_register');

function giving_register() {

  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Invest Items', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Item', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'giving item'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Item'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Item'),
    'new_item' => __('New Item'),
    'view_item' => __('View Item'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Items'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/cpt-giving.png',
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'giving_items' ),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title','thumbnail','editor'),
    'paged' => false,
    ); 

  register_post_type( 'givings' , $args );
}

register_post_type( 'givings' , $args );

add_action("admin_init", "giving_admin_init");

function giving_admin_init(){
  add_meta_box("giving_info-meta", "Item Options", "giving_info", "givings", "side", "high");
}

function giving_info(){
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $amount = $custom["amount"][0];
  $monthly = $custom["monthly"][0];
  $user_entered_value = $custom["user_entered_value"][0];
  $item_name = $custom["item_name"][0];
  $special = $custom["special"][0];
  ?>
  <div style="text-align: right;">
    <p>
      <label for="amount"><strong>Amount:</strong></label>  
      <input style="width: 180px" type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>" />
      <em>Example: 30.00</em>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="monthly"><strong>Monthly?</strong></label>  
      <?php if ($monthly == 'on') { ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="monthly" id="monthly" checked="checked" />
      <?php } else { ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="monthly" id="monthly" />
      <?php } ?>      
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="special"><strong>Special Item?</strong></label>  
      <?php if ($special == 'on') { ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="special" id="special" checked="checked" />
      <?php } else { ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="special" id="special" />
      <?php } ?>      
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="user_entered_value"><strong>Allow Giver To Enter Custom Value?</strong></label>  
      <?php if ($user_entered_value == 'on') { ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="user_entered_value" id="user_entered_value" checked="checked" />
      <?php } else { ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="user_entered_value" id="user_entered_value" />
      <?php } ?>      
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="item_name"><strong>Item Name:</strong></label>              
      <input style="width: 180px" type="text" name="item_name" id="item_name" value="<?php echo $item_name; ?>" /><br />
      If item is a <em>per item</em> then enter the name of the singular item. <em>Example: Chair - which will be displayed as "30.00 per Chair"</em>
    </p>
    <p style="text-align: left;">
      Strategic Giving photo must be horizontal and uploaded/set as the <strong>Featured Image</strong> (see below).
      <em>Do not add photo to content area.</em>
    </p>
  </div>
  <?php }  

add_action('save_post', 'giving_save_details_amount');
add_action('save_post', 'giving_save_details_monthly');
add_action('save_post', 'giving_save_details_user_entered_value');
add_action('save_post', 'giving_save_details_item_name');
add_action('save_post', 'giving_save_details_special');

function giving_save_details_amount(){
  global $post;
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "amount", $_POST["amount"]);
}

function giving_save_details_monthly(){
  global $post;
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "monthly", $_POST["monthly"]);
}

function giving_save_details_user_entered_value(){
  global $post;
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "user_entered_value", $_POST["user_entered_value"]);
}

function giving_save_details_item_name(){
  global $post;
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "item_name", $_POST["item_name"]);
}

function giving_save_details_special(){
  global $post;
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "special", $_POST["special"]);
}

add_action("manage_pages_custom_column",  "givings_custom_columns");
add_filter("manage_edit-givings_columns", "givings_edit_columns");

function givings_edit_columns($columns){
  $columns = array(
    "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
    "title" => "Strategic Giving Item",
    "amount" => "Amount",
    "monthly" => "Monthly",
    "special" => "Special Item",
    "giving_image" => "Image"
    );

  return $columns;
}

function givings_custom_columns($column){
  global $post;

  switch ($column) {
    case "amount":
    $custom = get_post_custom();
    echo $custom["amount"][0];
    break;

    case "monthly":
    $custom = get_post_custom();
    $is_monthly = $custom["monthly"][0];
    if ($is_monthly == "on") {
      echo "Yes";
    };
    break;

    case "special":
    $custom = get_post_custom();
    $is_special = $custom["special"][0];
    if ($is_special == "on") {
      echo "Yes";
    };
    break;

    case "giving_image":
      echo get_the_post_thumbnail(NULL, 'staff_admin');
    break;
  }
}

function giving_amount(){
  $custom = get_post_custom();
  return $custom["amount"][0];
}

function giving_monthly(){
  $custom = get_post_custom();
  return $custom["monthly"][0];
}

function giving_special(){
  $custom = get_post_custom();
  return $custom["special"][0];
}

function giving_user_entered_value(){
  $custom = get_post_custom();
  return $custom["user_entered_value"][0];
}

function giving_item_name(){
  $custom = get_post_custom();
  return $custom["item_name"][0];
}
```

**Update:** So I did more research and figured it out. Autosave (aka Revisions) - [Post metadata deletes itself](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5483/post-metadata-deletes-itself)

Is it possible to turn off autosave for just a single post type and not globally?

Comment: did you edit the code you posted above? Because you don't have `revisions` in the `supports` array, so Autosaves should be disabled for your "Givings" post type

Answer (score 17):

That's an easy one :)

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
function my_admin_enqueue_scripts() {
    if ( 'your_post_type' == get_post_type() )
        wp_dequeue_script( 'autosave' );
}
```

Comment: Not entirely clean. That script is needed if you want post.js to do permalink previews in the line under the title input.  It's especially noticeable on new posts, since the permalink line remains invisible without autosave. A workaround would be to enqueue a script that stubs in the essential objects and functions of autosave.js.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently de-registering the autosave javascript will essentially stop the autosave routine running. It won't necessarily disable the ability for autosaves to happen on that post type, but it will stop the native autosave script running.

It's not a perfect solution but it should have the desired effect.

```
function wpse5584_kill_autosave_on_postype( $src, $handle ) {
    global $typenow;
    if( 'autosave' != $handle || $typenow != 'your-post-type-here' )
        return $src;
    return '';
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'wpse5584_kill_autosave_on_postype', 10, 2 );
```

Hope that helps...

**EDIT:** With the above code, when on the post creation screen for that type you should see the following in the source of the page..

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var autosaveL10n = {
    autosaveInterval: "60",
    previewPageText: "Preview this Page",
    previewPostText: "Preview this Post",
    requestFile: "http://yoursite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    savingText: "Saving Draft&#8230;",
    saveAlert: "The changes you made will be lost if you navigate away from this page."
};
try{convertEntities(autosaveL10n);}catch(e){};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src=''></script>
```

The variables aren't what we're looking at here, it's the script at the bottom, notice the src now points nowhere (this was originally pointing at the autosave.js file).

Do you see something similar to the above, or is the src still getting written with the path to the autosave.js file?

**EDIT2:** This is what i see with concatenate scripts off.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&amp;load=hoverIntent,common,jquery-color,schedule,wp-ajax-response,suggest,wp-lists,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-sortable,postbox,post,word-count,thickbox,media-upload&amp;ver=e1039729e12ab87705c047de01b94e73'></script>
```

Notice that the autosave script is being excluded still.. (so thus far i'm unable to reproduce your problem)..

Where are you placing the code i provided?

Comment: Thanks!! Is it possible to put multiple post types in there? Or do I have to do this for each CPT?

Comment: Shame. It didn't work for a single cpt. I'm still getting this: http://cl.ly/3gTR - which is clearing the custom fields.

Comment: Check the source of the page and see if the autosave.js file is still there, if it's still there, then the filter isn't working as expected(or i'm missing something).. QUICK EDIT: Seems to work for me just fine, did you remember to change the text in sample code to match your post type?

Comment: Yeah I'll try again and look at the source. And what about if I want to do multiple post types?

Comment: Sooo rather than getting an 'autosave.js' file in the source it has the code right on the page (http://cl.ly/3gaf). Does that make sense? It shows up whether I have the code you gave me or not. Thanks!

Comment: See info added to answer, is that what you see, or are you seeing something different?

Comment: nope. it looks like this - http://cl.ly/3hla

Comment: Well that's because i have script concatenation switched off on my install, but i'm still not seeing what you see when i turn it back on, see my answer, i'm adding in what i see..

Comment: I'm placing the script you gave me in my functions.php file.

Comment: Exactly where i've been testing the code. Might sound silly... but you are definately putting this code into the correct functions.php file right, definately that of the active theme? I have to ask, just incase... :)

Comment: You said it's not a perfect solution, but it's not even a good solution :)

Comment: This is exactly was I was searching... Thank you for the script  t31os

Comment: So please tell me why... If the solution isn't good for whatever reason, provide me with the appropriate feedback to make adjustments to the answer. Help me help you.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a problem with this on one of the plugins I maintain, 
and we decided to just check if we were on our pages (wpsc-product and not on post or page) and then we simply deregistered the autosave script,, so,, out CPT is 'wpsc-product' and our function (removing unrelated code looks something like this:

```
function admin_include_css_and_js_refac( $pagehook ) {
    global $post_type, $current_screen;
    if($post_type == 'wpsc-product' )
    wp_deregister_script( 'autosave' );         
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_include_css_and_js_refac' );
```

Comment: Please don't deregister core scripts.