# Getting a "Changes you made will be lost" dialog prompt on a custom post type page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I have a simple custom post type setup with a few custom fields. All seems to be working ok until on the odd occasion I get the dialog box you normally see if you try to navigate away from a post/page with unsaved content. I am trying to navigate away from the page which is what triggers the dialog prompt - but I have already saved my content.

Has anyone previously come across any issue like this?

I think it's isolated to my custom post.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to solve this after I got lucky with a random search and found this.
[Post metadata deletes itself](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5483/post-metadata-deletes-itself)

There's also a decent thread on the problem here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539951/wordpress-add-meta-box-weirdness

Answer (score 0):

I actualy need some more information to help you out with this question. But because of stackexchange "amazing" reputation system I can't comment yet. I thus will answer this question with assuming a lot of stuff, hoping it will help you. If not we can comment on this answer.

For more information on the general message you can go here [link](http://www.404techsupport.com/2010/03/ask-404ts-whats-up-with-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-dialogs/). It talks about why, how, and where the messages comes from.

Possible problem/solution 1:
The messages has been linked to the TinyMCE Advanced plugin several times. So if you have this plugin installed, please deactivate it and see if this solves your issue. This plugin produces the exact problem you are suggesting every time you navigate away from a post, even if the post has been saved or no changes were ever made.

Futhermore it is always smart to deactive all plugins, and see if this solves the issue. There might be a conflict with one of your plugins

Possible problem/solution 2:
When you navigate away from the post/page edit screen, do you use the back/forward button in the explorer? This might conlfict with "save" in wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aleks - i've ruled out problem 2 and also tried deactivating plugins - no luck. re: problem 2 - I'm not navigating away via back buttons etc. I'm clicking links within the UI. I also note that when I choose to navigate away WordPress is actually deleting values in custom fields. What's weird is that it is not consistent behaviour. There must be a mistake in my custom post syntax somewhere I'm guessing